# How can I generate report from collection on daily, weekly and monthly basis MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pipeline

This is the structure of my collection

```
  {"_id":{
       "$oid":"61a5f45e7556f5670e50bd25"
    },
    "agent_id":"05046630001",
    "c_id":null,
    "agentName":"Testing",
    "agent_intercom_id":"4554",
    "campaign":[
       "Campaig227"
    ],
    "first_login_time":"28-12-2021  10":"55":42 AM,
    "last_logout_time":"21-01-2022  2":"20":10 PM,
    "parent_id":4663,
    "total_call":2,
    "outbound_call":1,
    "iinbound_call":1,
    "average_call_handling_time":56,
    "logged_in_duration":2,
    "total_in_call_time":30,
    "total_break_duration":10,
    "total_ring_time":2,
    "available_time":40,
    "ideal_time":0,
    "occupancy":0,
    "inbound_calls_missed":0,
    "created_at":{
       "$date":"2021-11-29T18:30:00.000Z"
    }
    }
```

I want to generate monthly result like this:

| Agent | Campaign | Total call | Outgoing | Incoming | Average Call | Total Time | Idle Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Agent 1 | Campaig227 | 148 | 38 | 62 | 12:00:18 | 12:46:45 | 0:23:57 |
| Agent 2 | Campaig227 | 120 | 58 | 62 | 16:00:18 | 16:46:45 | 0:23:57 |

and daily report like:

| Agent | Date | Campaign | Total call | Outgoing | Incoming | Average Call | Total Time | Idle Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Agent 1 | 1/1/22 | Campaig2 | 14 | 10 | 4 | 4:00:18 | 4:46:45 | 0:46:26 |
| Agent 1 | 2/1/22 | Campaig2 | 24 | 15 | 9 | 10:00:18 | 9:46:45 | 0:15:26 |
| Agent 2 | 1/1/22 | Campaig1 | 16 | 10 | 6 | 4:00:18 | 4:46:45 | 0:46:26 |
| Agent 2 | 2/1/22 | Campaig1 | 30 | 15 | 15 | 10:00:18 | 9:46:45 | 0:15:26 |

Please note that this is only sample data; the actual figure is different.

I tried to do this using aggregate and Pipeline but as I am new to MongoDB so find difficulty in generating query.

Comment: What did you try? [$dateTrunc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateTrunc/) should help you.

Comment: The timestamps are not valid. Please provide valid sample data.

Comment: $dateTrunc is not supported in mongodb version 4.1

Comment: For daily and monthly report you can group by `{_id: { date: { $dateToString: { date: "$created_at", format: "%Y-%m-%d" } } }}`, resp. `format: "%Y-%m"`. For weekly report try format `"%G-W%V"`

Answer (score 0):

On proposal would be this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $group: {
         _id: {
            agent_id: "$agent_id",
            campaign: "$campaign",
            date: {
               $dateTrunc: {
                  date: "$created_at",
                  unit: "week",
                  timezone: "Europe/Zurich",
                  startOfWeek: "monday"
               }
            }
         },
         "Total call": { $sum: "$total_in_call_time" },
         Outgoing: { $sum: "$outbound_call" },
         Incoming: { $sum: "$iinbound_call" },
         "Average Call": { $avg: "$total_in_call_time" },
         "Total Time": { $sum: "$total_call" },
         "Idle Time": { $sum: "$ideal_time" }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         "Average Call": { $dateToString: { date: { $toDate: { $multiply: ["$Average Call", 1000] } }, format: "%H:%M:%S" } },
         "Total Time": { $dateToString: { date: { $toDate: { $multiply: ["$Total Time", 1000] } }, format: "%H:%M:%S" } },
         "Idle Time": { $dateToString: { date: { $toDate: { $multiply: ["$Idle Time", 1000] } }, format: "%H:%M:%S" } }
      }
   },
   { $replaceWith: { $mergeObjects: ["$_id", "$$ROOT"] } },
   { $unset: "_id" }
])
```

Note, `$dateToString: {format: "%H:%M:%S"}` works for periods up to 24 hours.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LsoV6LSMkN9)